# ICommonQuery::OpenQueryWindow. No Administrative context menu in search results

Tags: c++, active-directory, dsquery

I tried to invoke Active directory search window from my application with administrative and other extended features. For this purpose I'm using such flags:

```
DSQPF_ENABLEADMINFEATURES | DSQPF_ENABLEADVANCEDFEATURES;
```

As described in MSDN:

**DSQPF_ENABLEADMINFEATURES** - Uses features supported by the directory service administration tools, such as Admin Display Specifier for ***context menus*** and ***property pages***.

**DSQPF_ENABLEADVANCEDFEATURES** - Specifies advanced features in the IDataObject instance passed to ***context menus*** and ***property pages***.

This two flags perfectly works for tabs. As Domain administrator I can see a lot of tab in properties of user. But This parameters hasn't influence on context menu. Here example:

1. Search dialog that was invoked from **Server Manager**. You can see administrative context menu.

[Server Manager Screenshot](http://s11.postimg.org/ihxkys1tf/Screenshot_Server_Console.png)

2. This is dialog invoked from my application. There is very short contexts menu, but if I'll click **Properties**, I'll be able to change everything related to this account with administrative privileges.

[Invoke from application Screenshot](http://s13.postimg.org/osekulgzr/Screenshot_AD_App.png)

Application runs from Domain Administrator. UAC is disabled. Tested on Windows Server 2008 R2.

**Is there any way to show this context menu?**

Here you can see example code that I used for invoking AD search dialog.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "activeds.h"
#include "cmnquery.h"
#include "dsquery.h"
#include "shlobj.h"
#include "dsclient.h"
#include "windows.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "uuid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "activeds.lib")

HRESULT FindADUsers(HWND hwndParent)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    ICommonQuery *pcq;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CommonQuery,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_ICommonQuery,
        (LPVOID*)&pcq);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        OPENQUERYWINDOW openQueryWindow;
        DSQUERYINITPARAMS dqip;
        IDataObject *pdo;

        ZeroMemory(&openQueryWindow, sizeof(openQueryWindow));
        openQueryWindow.cbStruct = sizeof(openQueryWindow);
        openQueryWindow.dwFlags = OQWF_DEFAULTFORM | OQWF_SINGLESELECT | OQWF_SHOWOPTIONAL;
        openQueryWindow.pHandlerParameters = &dqip;
        openQueryWindow.clsidHandler = CLSID_DsQuery;
        openQueryWindow.clsidDefaultForm = CLSID_DsFindPeople; 

        ZeroMemory(&dqip, sizeof(dqip));
        dqip.cbStruct = sizeof(dqip);
        dqip.dwFlags = DSQPF_NOSAVE | DSQPF_SHOWHIDDENOBJECTS | DSQPF_ENABLEADMINFEATURES | DSQPF_ENABLEADVANCEDFEATURES;

        hr = pcq->OpenQueryWindow(hwndParent, &openQueryWindow, &pdo);
        if (S_OK == hr)
        {
            pdo->Release();
        }

        pcq->Release();
    }

    return hr;
}

//  Entry point for application
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr;
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    hr = FindADUsers(NULL);
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```